# PRINCE2 certification vs. CSM certification

Tags: certification, prince2

I'm already PMI certified PMP, and would like to appear for the CSM training. Can you suggest whether I should go for [PRINCE2 certification](http://www.prince2.com/what-is-prince2.asp) or CSM certification?

I know about the value and need of both certification, but when we look at the industry where do we see a huge demand for which certification?

Comment: Where are you? Prince2 isn't commonin the US.

Answer (score 4):

Scrum and Prince2 operate on a completely different level.

As you can see in this post: [Can PRINCE2 and SCRUM work together?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/can-prince2-and-scrum-work-together)

Prince2 is on a PM level and Scrum is on product delivery level, so the position you are in, the environment, organisation and geographical position could be all factors that have an influence on your choice.

One isn't more valuable as the other, if you don't take into account the position you are in.

From my experience I would say (only indicative list, more options are possible):

Choose for Prince2 if you:

- are geographically positioned outside of USA (although it is growing there as well)
- want to know about PM, the terminology, the processes, etc.

Choose for Scrum if you:

- are using Scrum or any derivative like Scrumban

Answer (score 2):

I would go for prince2 and SCM after

**Updated after Brian's comment:**

First of all I'm not a great fun of certificates, but if I had to choose, my order would be prince2 and SCM after because:

- prince2 is a general while SCM is only for software development, so it values more
- Although SCM is very popular nowadays I believe that quite soon there won't be as many Scrum practitioners as today - organisations are changing from Scrum to Kanban or Scrumban or Scrumbut -, so it's value will decrease, on the other hand, there always will be a need for project managers, so the value of prince2 will be the same

Both certificates cost a lot of money, so I would go for the valuable at first.

Comment: Why? I'm not doubting your answer, but I would like to understand this better.

Comment: I've updated my answer, because it wasn't as detailed as it is supposed to be. Thanks for point it out

Comment: The assumption that if you use Scrumban or Scrumbut(which is in most cases used because of lack of knowledge) that you don't need a scrum practitioner is just wrong. Without good knowledge and all roles of Scrum, Scrumban is also doomed for failure.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree with you. Transformation to Scrumban or Scrumbut does not happen because of the missing knowledge. There are many cases which cannot be solved by Scrum. It is not as flexible as it is advertised. For example, flexible delivery dates, scaling on organisation level etc, but the topic which is about to start isn't related to the original question

Comment: I'm not saying that it comes from missing knowledge, I'm saying that to do Scrumban correctly, you need full understanding of Scrum.

Comment: I see, I was afraid that we're going to have a Scrum vs. Others discussion ;-) . I agree that the basic knowledge is necessary. I miss the vision from the SCM trainings. When I did it, I got tools for executing, but I got nothing to see the world differently.

Comment: I think you need more than just a 2 day course to really understand Scrum (or any Lean / Agile methodology) anyway. The CSM doesn't make you a practitioner, let alone a master.

Comment: That is so true.

Answer (score 0):

Which is better for you depends entirely on what you are doing now and where you plan to be.

If you do agile without much emphasis on Prince2 then go for CSM first. If you are in a Prince2 organization that dabbles in agile then go for your Prince2 first.

If you are looking to the future Prince2 may be more portable if you leave an agile environment. In North America Prince2 is more government work, but even there jrosell is right that PMP is much more common.

Answer (score 0):

CSM is currently in an early phase. I think it's only worth if your organization uses Scrum or you want get some exposure. In any case, you should go further in the scrum certifications list if you really want to use it as a credential of your scrum knowledge. To obtain it you only need to attend a 2 days training, by a certified scrum teacher, and take an online exam that, at least in April, doesn't have a minimum punctuation to pass.

Prince, I don't know exactly, but I know PMP, and my experience is that it will help you to get a wider perspective on project management techniques and terminology.

In any case, both Prince and Scrum are quite different philosophies, Prince more formal and Scrum more 'new age'. I consider though that any PM must have some formal PM training before moving to Agile-like methodologies so that he is aware what is getting simplified or minimized, because some assessments in Agile are just implicits and the points must still be considered when undertaking a project.